# TypeError: type 'types.GenericAlias' is not an acceptable base type

Tags: python, python-3.9, nuitka

Okay so I compiled my python project into an executable and it worked on my computer but I sent it to a couple of friends to test and they all got this error. I have never seen an error like this before. I used Nuitka to compile the code.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python39\lib\inspect.py", line 35, in <module>
> import ast   File "C:\Python39\lib\ast.py", line 29, in <module>
> from contextlib import contextmanager, nullcontext   File "C:\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 4, in <module>
> import _collections_abc   File "C:\Python39\lib_collections_abc.py", line 416, in <module>
> class _CallableGenericAlias(GenericAlias): TypeError: type 'types.GenericAlias' is not an acceptable base type`
> ```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with mixing Python versions.

Comment: But with Nuitka it creates a python 3.9 dll so shouldn't the executable use that then? Also, how can I make it so the user doesn't have to install the python libraries I used when trying to run the executable?

Comment: I guess you compiled with an earlier python version that your friends. I just had this same error to discover at the end that I compiled with a 3.9.1 (the latest at that moment) and I used it later with a docker based on 3.9.16. Try and recompile with a newer 3.9 version.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm very late for this but it might help someone in the future,

**Caution: This solution involves messing around with source files and I was comfortable with that because I was using it in an isolated conda environment. Make sure you understand what you're doing before implementing it because clearly I DON'T.**

I applied the solution pointed out [in this post](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/F3ypHrQaE9c?pli=1) and it somehow solved the issue for me.

Basically I went into the source _collections_abc.py source file and swapped the variable `GenericAlias` in `_CallableGenericAlias(GenericAlias) to _CallableGenericAlias(GenericAlias)` which was declared at the beginning as `GenericAlias = type(list[int])` to `_CallableGenericAlias(GenericAlias) to _CallableGenericAlias(list[int])`

**Again, use with caution, because I also don't fully understand what's going on.**

Original post found [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=980906)

Comment: Similar situation, probably bad install of Python in the conda environment. Happened to me after creating a new conda environment using mamba: `mamba create -n ... python=3.9` with resulting Python 3.9.1. The changes in the answer do fix the issue as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

### ImportError Compiling with Nuitka

1. Make sure you are providing the right path for compilation

For example, if you want to compile an executable module with a `__main__` file, then you can provide the module package path as the following:

```
python -m nuitka --onefile --follow-imports --output-filename=<my_executable_name> <my_package_path>
```

2. Make sure there isn't a **`type`** module in the root package (any other ImportError might be resolved in the same way)

---

This is error is likely happening because of a name conflict between yours and standard library's module (type).